# How to calculate total cost for an Organization when they call the API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I have designed a collection named `Organization` as follows:
with `name` is the name of the organization, `desc` is a description of the organization, `id_app` is an array of applications for that `organization`

1- Below is `Organization`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64b4b8bc3975804004fa81b4"),
    "id_app" : [
        ObjectId("64b4b842a5831248e8a6b65c"),
        ObjectId("64b4b34f54106c24dc018992")
    ],
    "is_deleted" : false,
    "name" : "Org1",
    "desc" : "Org1 desc",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-07-17T03:42:52.845+0000"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2023-07-17T03:42:52.845+0000"),
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

2- Bellow is `Application` collection:

with `id_api` is an array of the `apis` that application calls

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64b4b34f54106c24dc018992"),
    "id_api" : [
        ObjectId("64b4ac07c4784418986870dc"),
        ObjectId("64b4abcdc4784418986870d7")
    ],
    "is_deleted" : false,
    "name" : "app1",
    "desc" : "app1 desc",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-07-17T03:19:43.573+0000"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2023-07-17T03:19:43.573+0000"),
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

3- Bellow is `Apis` collection:

with `name` is the API name, `desc` is the api description, `URL` is the path of the API and
`field` is the field of that api, for example education api.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64b4abcdc4784418986870d7"),
    "is_deleted" : false,
    "name" : "api1",
    "desc" : "Api 1 desc",
    "URL" : "http://localhost:8080/api/api1",
    "field" : "edu",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-07-17T02:47:41.849+0000"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2023-07-17T02:47:41.849+0000"),
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Each time an `app` calls an `API`, a fee will be generated (eg cost1 = 10$ ), and a collection named `Billing` will be created.

4- And below is `Billing` collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64b4c3d6068f5537e4bbd01b"),
    "is_deleted" : false,
    "cost1" : NumberInt(10),
    "cost2" : NumberInt(5),
    "cost3" : NumberInt(3),
    "id_app" : ObjectId("64b4b842a5831248e8a6b65c"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-07-17T04:30:14.646+0000"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2023-07-17T04:30:14.646+0000"),
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

While there are `Organation`, `Application`, `Apis`, and `Billing` collections. So the question is, how to calculate the billing amount (total cost) that an organization is charged when their apps call the API.

Thanks you so much

Comment: Are the `"id_app"` values unique to an organization?  If not, how can the organization be determined from the `Billing` collection documents?

Comment: No, by natural logic, an organization can have many apps, so `id_app` is an array of apps belonging to that organization. This way we can know, which application calls the API the most, helping us to have better statistics

Comment: Can two (or more) independent organizations share identical `"id_app"` values?

Comment: No, each Organization will created they own id_app

Comment: Do you need the total cost for a single organization?  ... a list of organizations?  ... all organizations?  Is the total calculated over all time?  ... by day?  ... by week?  ... by month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can app ids from organization collection using organization id

```
    db.getCollection('organization').find({_id: ObjectId("64b4b8bc3975804004fa81b4")});
```

2. And next you can use aggregate using application ids

```
    db.getCollection('Billing').aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                id_app: {
                    $in: [ObjectId("64b4b842a5831248e8a6b65c"), ObjectId("64b4b34f54106c24dc018992")
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null, totalCost: {
                    $sum: "$cost1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

3. The result

```
    {
        "_id" : null,
        "totalCost" : 10
    }
```

4. You can use following query to calculate total cost in a unique query

```
 db.getCollection('Billing').aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                id_app: {
                    $in: [ObjectId("64b646f602dbe6f481912d85"), ObjectId("64b4b34f54106c24dc018992")
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                totalCost: {
                    $sum: ["$cost1", "$cost2", "$cost3"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks you, how can i count total cost in a unique query ( includes $cost1, $cost2, $cost3). Thanks you

Comment: Please check again my answer. I have added 4.

Comment: If you have any questions, please send it to my gmail. nazar.zaplatinskiy20@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks you so much, I will send by mail if i have any questions